# Scaffold-DbContext doesn't produce models

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, model, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am trying to run `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate some models from an old system. I am running the following command:

`Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MAINT_TRAINING;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

The problem is that I get *absolutely* no output... No models, no errors, no confirmations...

The tables in the DB all have primary keys.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding `-Verbose` parameter?

Comment: Having same issue with .NET 6.0.202, VS 2022, EF 7.0.4
Provider is MySql.EntityframeworkCore 7.0.0
MySql Connector is 8.0.32
Tried both Package Manager Console and .NET CLI

Answer (score 2):

You may be hitting issue [#10298](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10298). Try adding the following to your `*.csproj`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: For those new to .NET & VS2017: In Solution Explorer, right-click [Your Project Name], and select "Edit [Your Project Name].csproj" to add this. It didn't have any effect & I still have no output from `Scaffold-DbContext...` but at least now I know how to edit the project file.